# How to return one array from firebase-database list of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with firebase and javascript. I am trying to return one array from firebase-database after executing a query from two tables. When I console.log my data I get a separate array and object for each bit of data.

```
var userId = 'hirerId';
var chatIdRef = firebase.database().ref("members");
var chatsRef = firebase.database().ref("chats");

chatIdRef.child(userId).on('child_added', snap => {
    chatsRef.child(snap.key).once('value', snap => {
     items = [];

       items.push({
         text: snap.val().text,
         chatId: snap.key
       });
         console.log(items);

      });
     });
```

This logs two separate arrays and objects: `[{"text":"How are you","chatId":"chatId"}] [{"text":"Hi friend","chatId":"chatId2"}]`

My desired result is `[{"text": "How are you","chatId":"chatId"}, {"text":"Hi friend","chatId":"chatId2"}]`

This is my data structure:
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCLMb.png)

How can I achieve my desired result? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `Array.concat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use apply.push to join as many arrays as you want. However, you might want to move your items = []; array outside the function. That's what is causing your problem. You are emptying the array every time you push/function fires.

```js
var ar1 = [{
  "text": "How are you",
  "chatId": "chatId"
}];
var ar2 = [{
  "text": "Hi friend",
  "chatId": "chatId2"
}];

ar1.push.apply(ar1, ar2);

console.log(ar1);
```

Comment: Thank you. moving items=[] outside the function worked.